# Can ping DC from client, cannot join domain

Tags: active-directory, domain, windows-server-2016

All VMs, closed network, all firewalls are off, all machines are on the same VLAN, all running Server 2016.  DC, DHCP, and DNS all set on a single machine (HostVM is the only DC).  All IP addresses are statically assigned.  Scope on VMHost is setup with IPs outside of the clients in question.

Clients can ping the IP address of the DC VM, the name of the DC VM, and the name of the domain.  When trying to join the domain I get "DNS does not exist" and "One or more of the following zones do not include delegation to its child zone:

domain.local

local

. (the root zone)

---

IPv6 is disabled on all machines.  DNS Server on the client is set to the IP of the DC and is listed on the DNS Advanced tab for DNS server addresses.

---

On the DC, the DNS Server address is the IP of the DC first and then loopback as alternate (I have tried loopback only to no avail).

---

Reverse lookup zone is created.

The Forward Zone is missing DomainDnsZones, and ForestDnsZones as well as _sites, _tcp, and _udp.

nslookup -q=srv _ldap.tcp.dc_msdcs.domain.local results in "HostVM can't find _ldap.tcp.dc_msdcs.domain.local: Non-existent domain"

Comment: have you tried to join domain with NetBIOS?

Comment: It does join with NetBIOS but we need it to join via DNS.

Comment: One particular question is why is the Forward Zone missing ForestDnsZones and all the rest?